# Count the amount of 'is available'

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have tried to figure out a solution for this problem, but can't really seem to figure out a way in my head, so hopefully someone has a simple and smart solution for this problem.

As you can see for the output example. It echoes " is available" next to the available timeslots for my code, but I would like to somehow make, so I can count or echo something like "There is no available times", if a day is fully booked.

I have tried some solutions with using $i = 0 and then $i++, but can't really seems to get it to work like I would.

Output example for code below:

> 2015-11-18 09:00:00 to 2015-11-18 09:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 09:30:00 to 2015-11-18 10:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 10:00:00 to 2015-11-18 10:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 10:30:00 to 2015-11-18 11:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 11:00:00 to 2015-11-18 11:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 11:30:00 to 2015-11-18 12:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 12:00:00 to 2015-11-18 12:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 12:30:00 to 2015-11-18 13:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 13:00:00 to 2015-11-18 13:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 13:30:00 to 2015-11-18 14:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 14:00:00 to 2015-11-18 14:30:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 14:30:00 to 2015-11-18 15:00:00
>
> 2015-11-18 15:00:00 to 2015-11-18 15:30:00
>
> 2015-11-18 15:30:00 to 2015-11-18 16:00:00 is available
>
> 2015-11-18 16:00:00 to 2015-11-18 16:30:00 is available

I use http://carbon.nesbot.com/ for the Carbon required in the top.

```
<?php
require 'Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

$schedule = [
    'start' => '2015-11-18 06:00:00',
    'end' => '2015-11-18 18:00:00',
];

$start = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['start']));
$end = Carbon::instance(new DateTime($schedule['end']));

$minInterval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$reqInterval = new DateInterval('PT45M');

$events = [
    [
        'created_at' => '2015-11-18 10:00:00',
        'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 13:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'created_at' => '2015-11-18 14:00:00',
        'updated_at' => '2015-11-18 16:00:00',
    ],
];

function slotAvailable($from, $to, $events, $workEnd){
    foreach($events as $event){
        $eventStart = new DateTime($event['created_at']);
        $eventEnd = new DateTime($event['updated_at']);

        if(($from >= $eventStart && $to <= $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventEnd && $to > $eventEnd) || ($from < $eventStart && $to > $eventStart) || ($to > $workEnd)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

foreach(new DatePeriod($start, $minInterval, $end) as $slot){
    $to = $slot->copy()->add($reqInterval);
    $workEnd = $schedule['end'];

    echo $slot->toDateTimeString() . ' to ' . $to->toDateTimeString();

    if(slotAvailable($slot, $to, $events, $workEnd)){
        echo ' is available';
    }
    echo '<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a counter before your last foreach loop.

```
$available = 0;
```

Then each time you echo "is available" you add 1 to it

```
$available++;
```

Then at the end...

```
if ($available == 0) echo "Day is fully booked";
```

If you meant that you wanted to show "Day is fully booked" instead of showing any of the schedule items, you should add all the things you echo to a string list instead and display it at the end if `$available > 0`.

```
$output = array();

...

// change all instances of echo ... to something like this...
// echo $slot->toDateTimeString() . ' to ' . $to->toDateTimeString();
array_push($output, $slot->toDateTimeString() . ' to ' . $to->toDateTimeString());

...

if ($available > 0) {
    foreach ($output as $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
} else {
    echo "Schedule is fully booked.";
}
```